# Flutter Alert Dialog doesn't work/displaying

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

So I am facing this problem that my alert Dialog isn't displaying. I had tried every possible solution and searching here and there but nothing works. When I click on the edit button from the pop up menu nothing is displayed everything remains the same.
[image]

**Calling alert Dialog**

```
trailing: PopupMenuButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                              itemBuilder: (context)=>[
                                PopupMenuItem(
                                    value:1,
                                    onTap: (){
                                      //debugPrint('popup');
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                      _showMyDialog();
                                    },
                                    child: ListTile(
                                  leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                  title: Text('Edit'),
                                )),
                                PopupMenuItem(
                                    value:1,
                                    // onTap: (){
                                    //   Navigator.pop(context);
                                    //   showDialogBox();
                                    // },
                                    child: ListTile(
                                  leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  title: Text('Delete'),
                                )),
                              ]),
```

**Alert Dialog Code**

```
Future<void> showDialogBox(String title)async{
editController.text=title;
debugPrint('dialog');
return showDialog<void>(
   context: context,
   barrierDismissible: false,
   builder: (BuildContext context){
     debugPrint('alert');
     return AlertDialog(
       title: Text('Update'),
       content: Container(
         child: TextFormField(
           controller: editController,
         ),
       ),
       actions: [
         TextButton(onPressed: (){
           Navigator.pop(context);
         }, child: Text('Update')),
         TextButton(onPressed: (){
           Navigator.pop(context);
         }, child: Text('Cancel')),
       ],
     );
   }
```

);
}
**Complete Class Code**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:firebase_tutorial/utils/routes/routes_names.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import '../../utils/utils.dart';
class PostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PostScreen> createState() => _PostScreenState();
}

class _PostScreenState extends State<PostScreen> {
  final ref=FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Post');
  FirebaseAuth _auth=FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final searchController=TextEditingController();
  final editController=TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: ()async{
        SystemNavigator.pop();
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Text('Post Screen'),
          actions: [
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  _auth.signOut().then((value){
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, RoutesNames.loginScreen);
                  }).onError((error, stackTrace){
                    Utils().toastMessage(error.toString());
                  });
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.logout_outlined)),
            SizedBox(width: 10,),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed:(){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, RoutesNames.newPost);
            },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            // Expanded(
            //     child:FirebaseAnimatedList(
            //         query: ref,
            //         itemBuilder: (context,snapshot,animation,index){
            //           return ListTile(
            //             title: Text(snapshot.child('post').value.toString()),
            //           );
            //         }
            //     ),
            // ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (String value){
                  setState(() {

                  });
                },
                controller: searchController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: "Search",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: ref.onValue,
                builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<DatabaseEvent> snapshot){
                  if(!snapshot.hasData){
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                  else{
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context,index){
                          Map<dynamic,dynamic> map=snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as dynamic;
                          List<dynamic> list=[];
                          list.clear();
                          list=map.values.toList();
                          final title=list[index]['post'].toString();
                          if(searchController.text.isEmpty){
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(list[index]['post']),
                              subtitle: Text(list[index]['id'].toString()),
                              trailing: PopupMenuButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                                  itemBuilder: (context)=>[
                                    PopupMenuItem(
                                        value:1,
                                        onTap: (){
                                          //debugPrint('popup');
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                          _showMyDialog();
                                        },
                                        child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                      title: Text('Edit'),
                                    )),
                                    PopupMenuItem(
                                        value:1,
                                        // onTap: (){
                                        //   Navigator.pop(context);
                                        //   showDialogBox();
                                        // },
                                        child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                      title: Text('Delete'),
                                    )),
                                  ]),
                            );
                          }
                          else if(title.toLowerCase().contains(searchController.text.toLowerCase())){
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(list[index]['post']),
                              subtitle: Text(list[index]['id'].toString()),
                            );
                          }
                          else{
                            return Container();
                          }


                        });
                  }

            }))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Future<void> showDialogBox(String title)async{
    editController.text=title;
    debugPrint('dialog');
    return showDialog<void>(
       context: context,
       barrierDismissible: false,
       builder: (BuildContext context){
         debugPrint('alert');
         return AlertDialog(
           title: Text('Update'),
           content: Container(
             child: TextFormField(
               controller: editController,
             ),
           ),
           actions: [
             TextButton(onPressed: (){
               Navigator.pop(context);
             }, child: Text('Update')),
             TextButton(onPressed: (){
               Navigator.pop(context);
             }, child: Text('Cancel')),
           ],
         );
       }
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding a delay before calling showDialog like this:

```
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10));
```

Your dialog isnt displayed because when you select a menu item the pop() method is automatically called to close the popup menu; so if you open a dialog immediately, the dialog will get automatically popped.
hope this fixes your issue

Comment: Thank you so much for your help its work but only when i remove the pop statement. With the pop statement it actually pop the home screen and go to the splash screen but whenever i remove the pop state and added a delay as you said it works

Comment: But it still works the same because when the alert dialog displayed the pop menu get popped itself. All thanks to you

Comment: You're very welcome. No you don't need to call the pop() method, it gets called automatically when you select a menu item, and that's exactly why your dialog wasn't showing. I'm happy I could help. if the answer worked, I would appreciate it if you accept the answer. thank you